# How do I plot multiple series in Jupyter using pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My data frame looks like this:

```
Year Month Count
2008    2   2
2008    6   1
2008    11  4
2008    12  2
2009    7   1
2009    8   1
2009    9   3
2009    11  5
2009    12  5
2010    1   2
2010    2   7
2010    3   6
.
.
.
```

I would like to plot Month on the x-axis and Count on the y-axis with each year representing a different series. How do I do this in Jupyter using pandas and matplotlib?

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Month', y='Count', hue='Year')`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Do you know how I can increase the size? There are 12 lines, one for each year, and with the graph being so small, it's hard to see any trend. 

I tried this but it didn't work: plot_con_month_trend.fig.set_size_inches(5,5)

Comment: do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))` and pass `ax=ax` to `sns.lineplot`.